# Fractional but not integer multi-commodity minimum cost flow

Tags: graph-theory, examples, multicommodity-flow

I'm searching for an example digraph for the multi-commodity minimum cost flow problem with integer demand. There shouldn't be an integer but fractional optimal solution. I found [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21913/can-the-optimal-minimum-cost-two-commodities-flow-be-fractional-on-this-special) a similar question but it considers an undirected graph or to be precise I don't catch Andreas Björklund's last comment.

Can anyone help? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Schrijver's book on Combinatorial Optimization discusses several aspects of multiflows in Vol C.

Comment: Just to add another variant to the puzzle: what would be the minimal example for a fractional optimal solution to a 2-commodity network flow problem where the underlying directed network has no cycles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the example for an undirected edge with unit capacities, but replace each undirected edge from A to B with a set of directed edges that look like this.

[image]

Each edge has a unit capacity. And if you have $x$ units of flow from A to B and $y$ units of flow from B to A, you can route it as long as $x+y \leq 1$.

This is the gadget referred to in Andreas Björklund's comment.